# Kali: Bluetooth adapter is not working

Tags: debian, drivers, kali-linux, bluetooth

My Bluetooth adapter is not working.

I tried to connect to my device using graphical interface, but the button connects not working.

So, I had to use command line, but this time I get the error:

```
root # /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
[....] Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.serviceJob for bluetooth.service failed. See 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

and when I tried to get more details:

```
root # systemctl -l status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-05-01 21:04:08 EDT; 23s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 9950 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9950 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Starting up"

May 01 21:04:08 user bluetoothd[9950]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
May 01 21:04:08 user bluetoothd[9950]: D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
May 01 21:04:08 user systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 21:04:08 user systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
May 01 21:04:08 user systemd[1]: Unit bluetooth.service entered failed state.


root #lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0930:0220 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root # lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

kali version:

> 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux